# IBM MQ Handling the connection during client-side application lifecycle

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I have to design our framework architecture for making connections, putting and consuming messages from IBM MQ (v8.0.0.5). I have to make multiple connections to several Queue Managers. In other words, we are the client-side.

When in a client side scenario, I mean when we send (put) messages to IBM MQ,
what's the best practice for the objects `MQQueue` and `MQQueueManager`?

> Set up and keep the connection as singleton during the whole
>   application life cycle and dispose the connection when application is
>   shutting down? Whenever I have to send a message, then I can call the 
>   singleton `MQQueue` object.

I'm just asking myself if this is the best practice?

Other way is to:

> Whenever we send a message, we connect/disconnect.

I have to say; The software will be installed as a windows service and whenever an event occurs, we will be sending messages to IBM MQ. I appreciate any help!

**EDIT**

We are using `C#`

Comment: Look at my answer to [Amqmdnet - Is it performant to open/close the queue for each message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001872/amqmdnet-is-it-performant-to-open-close-the-queue-for-each-message/46003942#46003942)

Comment: Since you are sending lot of messages, create connection once and keep the queue open till your finish sending messages. Opening a connection and queue, closing them for every message are a costly operation.

Comment: @Shashi With a lot of messages I actually didn't mean we have a list of a lot of messages to be sent through a foreach loop or something. We will be having a service which will be up all the time which will send IBM MQ messages whenever a call is incoming in our service.

Comment: Here is a simple rule I use, if the application/service will be sending more than 1 message per minute then it is better to connect, open and hold the information.  Remember to think long term, not just today.