# How to safely use .NET MQQueueManager in a WEB API application?

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

In an implicit multi-threaded environment like WebAPI, how can one safely use MQQueueManager() ? Is a singleton (static), for the lifetime of the service, a good approach ? Or a "init per request" approach suitable ?

The typical steps I have used is

- Initialize the queue manager
- Initialize the queues
- PUT something on the queue
- Close the queue
- GET something from the response queue
- Close the queue
- Disconnect the queue manager.

Note that this has to be done for EACH Web API request and results in longer response times. (much of that time is the MQQueueManager init). Also, after the init, at each step, for an exception we have to ensure that the queue manager is disconnected, otherwise the client connections add up.

Next obvious choice is to use a single static instance of the MQQueueManager  for the lifetime of the service. Because of a single instance here, the response time improvement is as high as 500%. *However, the problem here is that MQQueueManager tends to lock up after some time with and I start getting errors (error code 2009, 2059 etc.).*

**UPDATE 1**
When we have a static version of MQQueueManager class, the very first failure after a period of inactivity is *Completion Code 2, Reason 2009*, subsequent calls result in **Completion Code 2, Reason 2018**. Note that if we restart the app pool, normal functionality is resumed. We can put and get messages from the queues even under heavy load conditions.

**UPDATE 2 (pseudocode to illustrate my steps)**

```cs
public MQHelperClass
{

    static MQQueueManager mqmgr; // This is the actual MQeuemanager.
    static Hashtable connectionProperties;
    static MQQueue replyQueue;

    // Static constructor so that the MQQueueManager object
    // lasts the entirity of the app lifecycle once initialized
    static MQHelperClass
    {
        InitializeQueueManager();

    }

    static InitializeQueueManager()
    {
        // Set up connection properties
        connectionProperties = new Hashtable();

        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "XXXXXX"); 
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "XXXXXX");
        :
        :
        :
        mqQueManager = new MQQueueManager();

    }

    public void PutMessage(string)
    {
       //Put someting and then close;
    }

    public string GetMessage(string )
    {
    try
            {                
                MQQueue queue = AccessQueue(replyQueue,
                                    new int[] { MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF, MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING });


                MQMessage replyMessage = new MQMessage();
                MQGetMessageOptions getMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions()
                {
                    //MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID,
                    Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT,
                    WaitInterval = 30000
                };

                replyMessage.CorrelationId = messageId;
                queue.Get(replyMessage, getMessageOptions);
                string receivedMessage = replyMessage.ReadString(replyMessage.MessageLength);
                log.Debug($"Message received : {receivedMessage}");               
                queue.Close();                
                return receivedMessage;                    

            }
    }
}

public class MyApiController : ApiController 
{

    MQHelperClass helperClass = new MQHelperClass();

    helperClass.Put();
    helperClass.Get();
    :
    :
    :


}

        private static MQQueue AccessQueue(string queueName, params int[] 
        queueOpenOptions)
        {
            mqQueue = mqQMgr.AccessQueue(queueName, queueOpenOptions.Sum());
            return mqQueue;
        }
```

Comment: Usually connection pooling would be the answer for something like this. I don't know anything about this environment - can you use connection pooling here? Perhaps you have to write your own connection pooling at this point (which should also handle any errors that happen after some time, reconnecting when necessary).

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of your code?  Enabling RECONNECT will take care of disconnections.

Comment: @JoshMc Updated with my pseudo code. Also, how can we use RECONNECT for the .NET version of MQQueueManager.

Comment: A few more questions. can you provide details (even if scrubbed) of what properties you set for the the `connectionProperties`, also what version of MQ is the dll from and what version if MQ is the queue manager you connect to.

Comment: connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
            connectionProperties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "XXXXXX");
            connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "XXXXXX");

Comment: Please add that to the question so it can be formatted. But in any case to answer your question on how to enable reconnect: `connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT);`.  If this answers your question I'll write up a quick answer.

Comment: @JoshMc - Yes, the reconnect flag resolved this problem. With the static queue manager working, I will try to get away from closing and re-opening queues after every read and write (we do it to separate queues). Because , I believe we are running into this issue now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001872/amqmdnet-is-it-performant-to-open-close-the-queue-for-each-message

Comment: What version of the `amqmdnet.dll` were you using?

Comment: It's version 9.0.3.1

Comment: I ask for the specific version since there are known issues with some older versions of amqmdnet.dll that have been fixed, these would cause intermittent disconnects during periods of no activity, I would guess you hit this, but v9.0.3.1 is not a real version of MQ, Just right click the dll and select "properties" and then go to the "Details" tab and look for the File version or Product Version (both are likely the same).  I assume you mean either 9.0.3 or 9.1.0.3.

Comment: You are correct. The version number is indeed 9.0.3.0 ..... Somebody had actually gone in and bumped up the version number of the dll. So, which version is the latest and greatest ? And will the connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT); be enough to take care of automatic reconnections ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Review this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937216/ibm-mq-client-disconnect-after-10-minutes-ibm-xms-illegalstateexception/56938259#56938259) for why I think you see 2009.  I wound suggest 9.1.0.4.  Reconnect masks this issue but is useful for other issues unrelated to the issue.